# Why does my php function not get data from JSON array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a page that pulls information about TV shows from the [TMDB](https://www.themoviedb.org/faq/api?language=en) as a json array with the help of the [TMDB-API Wrapper](https://github.com/Alvaroctal/TMDB-PHP-API). I am trying to get the page to display information  on a tv shows's ['network'].

I have written a function for this that loops through the network array but I can't get it to work.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

This is my function that does not work.

```
//Get networks
   public function getNetworks() {
        $networks = array();

        foreach($this->_data['networks'] as $data){
            $networks[] = new Network($data, $this->getName());
        }

        return $networks;
    }
```

Display.php

```
//Call the function and loop though results
 echo '  <li>Networks: <ul>';
            $networks = $tvShow->getNetworks();
            foreach($networks as $network){
                echo '<li>'. $network->getID() .'</li>';
            }
```

This does work (written in the wrapper not me)

```
 public function getSeasons() {
        $seasons = array();

        foreach($this->_data['seasons'] as $data){
            $seasons[] = new Season($data, $this->getID());
        }
    return $seasons;
}
```

This does work

```
//Get Network
public function getNetworks() {
        return $this->_data['networks'][0]['name'];
}
```

And then on display.php

```
echo '<b>'. $tvShow->getNetworks() .'</b>';
```

This is the json array

```
{
    "backdrop_path": "/c8A5IYqIT1ez15sqA8wX5tCDTmF.jpg",
    "created_by": [
        {
            "id": 1187819,
            "name": "Matthew Weiner",
            "profile_path": null
        }
    ],
    "episode_run_time": [
        47,
        45
    ],
    "first_air_date": "2007-07-19",
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Drama"
        }
    ],
    "homepage": "http://www.amc.com/shows/mad-men",
    "id": 1104,
    "in_production": false,
    "languages": [
        "en"
    ],
    "last_air_date": "2015-05-17",
    "name": "Mad Men",
    "networks": [
        {
            "id": 174,
            "name": "AMC"
        }
    ],
```

Tvshow Class

```
class TVShow{

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Class Variables
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private $_data;

    /**
     *  Construct Class
     *
     *  @param array $data An array with the data of the TVShow
     */
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->_data = $data;
    }
```

Comment: if you don't loop the network, does it work? have you debugged so far?

Comment: Do you mean to be using `getName()` in your `getNetworks` method? I noticed in the `getSeasons` method that does work, `getID()` is used where you are using `getName()`.

Comment: Have you created your own Network class? I don't see one in their API documentation.

Comment: I've added the TVshow class to the code. The code does not work if I use getID. If I don't loop I I DO get a result.